# How to solve 'Can't write to file tahoma.z' - fpdf add font error

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm using fpdf class file to generate pdf in my php program. I want to use true type font named tahoma. Generated **.z,.afm,.ttf,.php** files from a website.

I've included makefont.php in my program and used a function makefont(). But it shows me an error **"Can't write to file tahoma.z"**. I've done everything as per tutorial I read. I couldn't figure it out what mistake I've done. Please somebody help me out.

---

```
require('pdf/makefont/makefont.php');
    MakeFont("pdf/font/tahoma.ttf","cp1252","true");
```

I've checked availability of all the file and spelling too.

Answer (score 0):

I found what had I done wrong. No need for make any fonts since I have .php and .z files. I simply put on font directory and used "AddFont()" function. that's it.